# How to make to the power of a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code

```
LUT = [[1,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]
N = len(LUT[0])
P = 0.1
x = [((P)**h)*((1-P)**(N-h)) for h in range (0, N+1)]
```

x is list that I want to store the values of this equation at each value of `h` where `h` starts from `0` to `N`. When I run this script I get `'int' object is not iterable`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the stack trace

```
    in prb_table(LUT, P)
    152 def prb_table(LUT, P):
    153         N=len(list(LUT[0]))
--> 154         x = [((P)**h)*((1-P)**(N-h)) for h in range (0, N+1)]
    155         return x

    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: It worked fine for me. With N = 5 and P = 7 the result x is [-7776, 9072, -10584, 12348, -14406, 16807]

Comment: If LUT is a list of integers then `LUT[0]` will be an int, then `len(LUT[0])` will not make sense.

Comment: LUT is a list of lists,  so I want the length of the internal list and not the external one.

Comment: @motaha what value you have in `LUT` , can you print here?

Comment: If  Lut[0] doesn't have a len then len(Lut[0]) gives a TypeError, but no such error has been reported.  My conclusion is that """'int' object is not iterable""" is coming from a part of the script that has not been shown.

Comment: Running the full code worked for me with the result that x is [0.5904900000000001,
 0.06561,
 0.007290000000000002,
 0.0008100000000000003,
 9.000000000000002e-05,
 1.0000000000000003e-05]

Comment: Please show your full stack trace

Comment: Please print `LUT[0]` right before you do `N=len(LUT[0])`.  It is clear that what the computer thinks `LUT` is is not what you've got here.  There is almost certainly an error prior to calling `prb_table`.

Comment: A note - when you provide a minimal example, you should always copy and paste that minimal example and run it.  In this case, it works.  So your bug is somewhere else.

Comment: @Joel Ok, the problem was in the LUT as you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have provided is correct.  The error is somewhere else prior to you calling this function.  In particular `LUT[0]` is not what you have given.

Somehow `LUT[0]` is an integer rather than a list, so somewhere in the piece of code that calls your function there is a bug prior to entering this function.

Answer (score 3):

If `LUT` is not a list of iterables,you should do:

```
N = len(LUT)
```

not `len(LUT[0])`. Be sure that what you put inside `len` is an `iterable` like a `list`, a `tuple`, a `set`...

Answer (score 2):

You either want

```
N = len(LUT)
```

...Or need to figure out exactly what you're trying to get the length of.
The argument for len() needs to be some kind of sequence like a list or tuple.
LUT[0] appears to be a single element, not a list if it's giving you that error.